# Recursive routing causes maximum stack exceeded error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-compiler

I've got a `PageModule` which reference itself in it's routing. It works if I remove the circular dependency, start the app and then add it again. But not if I stop the server and start it again with the circular dependency already there. How can I solve this?

I have this router module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':pageId',
        loadChildren: 'app/routes/+dashboard/routes/+pages/routes/+page/page.module#PageModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})

export class PageRouterModule {}
```

Which is then imported into PageModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PageRouterModule
  ],
  exports: [PageRouterModule],
  declarations: [PageComponent]
})

export class PageModule {}
```

Apparently this was supposedly fixed as seen [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6309), but I've upgraded to the latest cli version which is `1.5.0` but the issue is still there.

Comment: Isn't this the correct behavior, PageModule will try to lazy load itself and it'll run into circular dependency.

Comment: @RohanArora Both yes and no, in scenarios where you don't know how many child routes there will be, you need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that changing this line:

```
loadChildren: 'app/routes/+dashboard/routes/+pages/routes/+page/page.module#PageModule'
```

To:

```
loadChildren: loadModule
```

Where `loadModule` is an exported `function`:

```
export function loadModule() {
  return PageModule;
}
```

In theory you can do `() => PageModule` too but that will cause a lambda error so you must use the exported function as shown above.

I hope this helps someone else.